# React: TypeError: items.map is not a function. Even though my state is an array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, use-state

**Issue:**
within my child component:
TypeError: items.map is not a function

I don't understand why not, I saw that others had this issue when they were mapping through something that wasn't an array. However mine clearly is. As seen on the fourth line in the parent component.

---

**Parent comp:**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import ListItem from '../components/listItem';

const Pagethree = () => {
const[items,setItem] = useState([]);
return(
    <div>
        <CreateItem items={items} setItem={setItem}/>
        <ListItem items={items}/>
    </div>
)
};

export default Pagethree;
```

**Child comp 1:**

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

const ListItem = (props) =>{
const {items} = props;
return(
    <div>
        <h1>list item comp</h1>
        <ul>
            {
            items.map((item, i) =>
                <div class="flex">
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    {item}
                    <button>delete</button>
                </div>
            )
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
)
};

export default ListItem;
```

**child component 2:**

```
import React from "react";

const CreateItem = (props) =>{
const {items, setItem} = props;
const addItem = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    setItem([...items, items]);
    setItem("");
    console.log(items);
}
return(
    <div>
        <h1>create item comp</h1>
        <form onsubmit={addItem}>
            <input type="text" value={items} onChange={e => setItem(e.target.value)}/>
            <button type="submit">add item</button>
        </form>
    </div>
)
};

export default CreateItem;
```

Comment: The code you posted looks fine to me. Does the error occur immediately or just after the first `setItem()` call? I am assuming you are setting `items` to something that's not an array there.

Comment: .map only works on arrays and i am afraid that items might have changed to object or any other data types .

Comment: Is this the entirety of the `Pagethree` component? What you have currently in your snippet is correct and shouldn't throw any errors. Are you later updating the `items` state? If so then please include all relevant code in your question. If you are updating state then please also share what you are updating it to (the ***value*** you enqueue).

Comment: I do have another component for creating the object. I added the code in above. As soon as I type anything into the input is when i get the error

Comment: Why are you setting items to the empty string in addItem? Why are you setting items to the event’s target.value in the on change?

Comment: You enqueue a state update (`setItem([...items, items]);`) and then enqueue another state update (`setItem("");`) that overwrites the previous state and mutates the state invariant, i.e. you changed the state from an array to a string. You then also console log the current state from the enclosure, which *isn't* what it will be updated to and rendered on a subsequent render cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what your goal is, but this may help. It's a basic form that adds individual items (on submit) to an items list.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const item = e.target.elements['itemInput'].value;
    setItems([...items, item]);
    e.target.reset();
  }
  const itemsDisplay = `Your items are: ${items.join(', ')}`;

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <p>{itemsDisplay}</p>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input name='itemInput' />
        <button type='submit'>Add Item</button>
      </form>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `setItem` on input change (in CreateItem) you’re setting the state on the parent component to a single (non-array) value. The subsequent render throws because items is no longer an array.